# VHDL How to convert 32 bit variable to 4 x 8bit std_logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl

I have a question which is probably in 2 parts:

I am using a (nominally 32 bit) integer variable which I would like to write to an 8 bit UART as 4 bytes (i.e., as binary data)

i.e. variable Count : integer range 0 to 2147483647;

How should I chop the 32 bit integer variable into 4 separate 8 bit std_logic_vectors as expected by my UART code, and how should I pass these to the UART one byte at a time ?

I am aware std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Count, 32)) will convert the integer variable into a 32 bit std_logic_vector, but then what ?  Should I create a 32 bit std_logic_vector, assign the converted Count value to it, then subdivide it using something like the following code ?  I realise the following assumes the count variable does not change during the 4 clock cycles, and assumes the UART can accept a new byte every clock cycle, and lacks any means of re-triggering the 4 byte transmit cycle, but am I on the right track here, or is there a better way ?

```
variable CountOut  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

process (clock)

   variable Index : integer range 0 to 4 := 0;

   begin

   if rising_edge(clock) then

      CountOut <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Count, 32);

      if (Index = 0) then
         UartData(7 downto 0) <= CountOut(31 downto 24);
         Index := 1;
      elsif (Index = 1) then
         UartData(7 downto 0) <= CountOut(23 downto 16);
         Index := 2;
      elsif (Index = 2) then
         UartData(7 downto 0) <= CountOut(15 downto 8);
         Index := 3;
      elsif (Index =31) then
         UartData(7 downto 0) <= CountOut(7 downto 0);
         Index := 4;
      else
         Index := Index;
      end if;

   end if;

end process;
```

Any comments or recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks,

MAI-AU.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track. I believe there are two basic solutions to this problem:

1. Register the output value as a 32-bit vector, and use different ranges for each output operation (as you did in your code example)
2. Register the output value as a 32-bit vector, and shift this value 8 bits at a time after each output operation. This way you can use the same range in all operations. The code below should give you an idea:

```
process (clock)
   variable Index: integer range 0 to 4 := 0;
begin
   if rising_edge(clock) then      
      if (Index = 0) then
         CountOut <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Count, 32));
         Index := Index + 1;
      elsif (Index < 4) then
         UartData <= CountOut(31 downto 24);
         CountOut <= CountOut sll 8;
         Index := Index + 1;
      end if;
   end if;
end process;
```

Also, please check your assignments, in your example CountOut is declared as a variable but is assigned to as a signal.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  You can do something to separate the the assignment to UartData using Index to allow a loop.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity union is
end entity;

architecture foo of union is
    type union32 is array (integer range 1 to 4) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal UartData:    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

TEST:
    process 
    variable quad:    union32;
    constant fourbytes:    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"deadbeef";
    begin

        quad := union32'(fourbytes(31 downto 24), fourbytes(23 downto 16),
                         fourbytes(15 downto 8),fourbytes(7 downto 0));

        for i in union32'RANGE loop
            wait for 9.6 us;
            UartData <= Quad(i);
        end loop; 

        wait for 9.6 us;  -- to display the last byte
        wait;  -- one ping only
    end process;
end architecture;
```

[image: Bytes accessed by index]

Or use a type conversion function to hide complexity:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity union is
    type union32 is array (integer range 1 to 4) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
end entity;

architecture fee of union is

    signal UartData:    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    function toquad (inp: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)) return union32 is
    begin
        return union32'(inp(31 downto 24), inp(23 downto 16),
                        inp(15 downto 8),  inp( 7 downto 0));
    end function;
begin

TEST:
    process 
    variable quad:    union32;
    constant fourbytes:    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"deadbeef";
    begin

        quad := toquad (fourbytes);

        for i in union32'RANGE loop
            wait for 9.6 us;
            UartData <= Quad(i);
        end loop; 

        wait for 9.6 us;  -- to display the last byte
        wait;  -- one ping only
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And gives the same answer.